# Delete rows in a table using a for-loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

My data is formatted as a table in Matlab: T =

```
  J K L M N O
  121 1 1 a1 3b 1.72
  121 2 1 2c 4d 1.43
  0 3 1 e3 5f nan
  299 4 1 g4 h5 1.64
  299 1 2 4i 4j 1.48
  0 2 2 6k nan 2.33
  0 3 2 m7 8n nan
  455 4 1 i4 j5 3.24
  4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

I would like to delete every row where I have a zero or 299 in columns J

I tried

```
number_of_rows = size(T,1);
for i=1:number_of_rows
    if T{i,1} == 299
        T(i,:) = [];
    end

     if T{i,1} == 0.0
         T(i,:) = [];
     end
end
```

But I get always an error:

> Row index exceeds table dimensions.

I tried to index my rows I want to delete:

```
number_of_rows = size(T,1);
todelete = zeros(size(T,1),1);

for ii=1:number_of_rows

    if (T{ii,1} == 8.4) || (T{ii,1} == 1.5)
       todelete(ii) = 1;
    end

end

T(todelete,:) = [];
```

But then I get an error I don't understand

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Why does `T(todelete,:) = [];` not work?

I just found a really good solution to my problem. I use the function

> find()

Then all I have to do is simply:

```
to_delete = find(T.K==0 | T.K==8.4);
T(to_delete,:) = [];
```

Comment: I think I know what's happening. You followed Ander's good advice and replaced the 'i' with 'ii'. It looks like you forgot to replace it somewhere and now you are accessing 'variable(i)' where 'i' stands for imaginary. So this error tells you that you are requesting an imaginary index (that's why it says it must be real).

Comment: It could also be that you are requesting acces to index 0, which would come from your todelete = zeros(...)

Comment: I found a really good solution:

Answer (score 2):

You go deleting rows!

Once you have a row deleted, `T` has not `numberrows1` anymore!

2 solutions:

1.-Create `Tdeleted=T;` and then replace `T(i,:) = [];` by `Tdeleted(i,:) = [];`

2.-Instead of deleting, go saving the indexes of rows you want to delete. Do `todelete(end+1)=i`. Then after the for loop do `T(todelete,:)=[];` and all rows  will be deleted at once.

PD: Do not use `i` s a variable name is Matlab, it is the [imaginary unit!](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) Use ii.

Comment: I try to work with your second solution. But how can I save the index of my rows?

Comment: @Samuel Its written there! `todelete(end+1)=ii;`

Answer (score 0):

You delete rows before your loop finished going over `T`. So if any row has been removed, your loop will try to access a row that has moved upwards and you get an index-out-of-bounds error.

```
numberrows1 = size(T,1);
for i=1:numberrows1
    if T{i,1} == 8.4
        T(i,:) = [];
    end

     if T{i,1} == 0.0
         T(i,:) = [];  % Here you remove a row. From now on size(T) is (numberrows-1,...)
     end
end
```

In matlab you usually don't want to manipulate variables in that way. In general a good approach would be to loop over `T` *without manipulating* it and store the indices of the rows you want removed. The easiest way is then to allocate a new `T_clean` which will hold the `T` without the deleted rows. Something like this should work:

```
numberrows1 = size(T,1);
deletion_indices = zeros(size(T,1),1);

for i=1:numberrows1
    if T{i,1} == 8.4
        T(i,:) = [];
    end

     if T{i,1} == 0.0
%          T(i,:) = cell(4,1);
        deletion_indices(i) = 1; % Flag for deletion
     end
end

% Allocate new T
new_numberrows1 = numberrows1 - sum(deletion_indices);
T_clean = cell( new_numberrows1, size(T,2) );

row_index = 1;
for iRow=1:new_numberrows1
    % Add row if it's not marked for deletion
    if ( ~deletion_indices(iRow) )
        T_clean(iRow,:) = T(row_index,:);
    end

    % Increase row_index
    row_index = row_index +1;
end
```

Comment: @Samuel Alright, I added a comment to your question which should help.